# as3: converting a txt file (string) to a tile-based array? using Tiled editor

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, text, converters

I am using Tiled to make tile maps.

I save them as .txt, and level one is as follows:

```
[header]
width=14
height=8
tilewidth=120
tileheight=120

[tilesets]
tileset=Tileset.png,120,120,0,0

[layer]
type=Tile Layer 1
data=
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

How would I make the data turn into something like:

```
        mapArr = [
        [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [  0,101,101,101,101,101,101,  0],
        [  0,101,  0,101,101,101,101,  0],
        [  0,101,101,101,101,  0,101,  0],
        [  0,101,101,101,101,101,102,  0],
        [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
        ];
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic example. It makes some assumptions about how the input text is formatted, but this should get you started.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

//create a loader and request object for data file
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("level1.txt");

//begin the load
try {
    loader.load(request);
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace("Unable to load requested document.");
}

//on load complete....
function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event) : void
{
    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
    parse(loader.data)
}

//parse the data file
function parse(data:String) : Array
{
    var lines = data.split('\n'); //split data file by lines
    var counter:int = lines.length -1; 
    var map:Array = new Array();

    //start from the last line. Keep adding rows until 'data=' line is found
    while(lines[counter] != "data=" && counter > 0)
    {
        var row:Array = lines[counter].split(',');
        if(row[row.length -1] == "")
        {
            row.pop(); //gets rid of trailing comma for all but last row
        }
        map.unshift(row);
        counter--;
    }

    //just to see how it looks
    for(var key in map)
    {
        trace("\n" + map[key]);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. it simply traces out the entire document, it doesn't make it like the example I showed

Comment: The parse function returns a variable with a two dimensional array representing the map from your input file. I put the trace is just in there so you could see the result.

Comment: So how do I get the actual result if not from the trcae?

Comment: You want this data stored somewhere in your program, yes? You get it as the result of the parse call in the loaderCompleteHandler. You can do anything you want with it. Assign it to a global variable like myGlobalLevelMap = parse(loader.data); or send that data to some function in your program that does something with the map i.e. doSomethingWithMap(parse(loader.data));